# load view randomly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

hi i wished to randomly load a view. the views are called view1 view2 and view3 below is the code im using. can any one tell me the the code i should  place in the case section to replace  - (void)viewDidLoad self.view = view1; etc as this is not working thanks

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

 NSString *title = nil;
 NSString *path = nil;

 int Number = arc4random() % 3;
 switch(Number) {
 case 0:
         - (void)viewDidLoad {
             self.view = view1;
         }

 break;
 case 1:
         - (void)viewDidLoad {
         self.view = view2;
         }

 break;

 case 2:
             - (void)viewDidLoad {
                self.view = view3;
             }

 break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
switch(Number) {
    case 0:
         self.view = view1;
         break;
    case 1:
         self.view = view2;
         break;
    case 2:
         self.view = view3;
         break;
}
```

Comment: Or, more simply: `id views[] = {view1, view2, view3}; self.view = views[Number];`

Comment: I thought I would match the solution as close to his code as possible so that he could spot why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the:

```
             - (void)viewDidLoad {
```

In each case statement, as well as the ending braces after it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code only defines the inner function in the function, and doesn't call it.

Comment: Did you compile it? Under my environment(Xcode 3.2.4 & SDK4.1), "'viewDidLoad' undeclared (first use in this function)" error appeared.

Comment: yes it did the same for me. ill going to start the whole project from scratch and go over every thing agin with more study material. the book i had that covered it i lent out and it disappeared into that black hole